# How to Register Custom IRouter in .NET 7 MVC Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, .net-7.0

I have a custom `IRouter` implementation and I can't figure out how to register it in a .NET 7 MVC application.

What I am trying to accomplish is this: Incoming requests have the form of `https://example.com/{id}` and when such a request comes in I need to hit the database to retrieve the controller and action for that `{id}`, do some checks on it and if everything looks right pass the request on to the default router along with the entire `RequestContext`. The reason behind that is that such an url is valid only for a given time and a subset of visiting users. Also the underlying action and controller must not be guessable by looking at the url.

What I came up with is a custom `IRouter` implementation (which also allows me to create those Urls) but I can't seem to figure out how to register on application startup.

Is using a custom `IRouter` still the right approach in .NET 7? How do I register one? Or am I totally on the wrong track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to switch back from endpoint routing:

```cs
builder.Services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false); 

app.UseMvc(routeBuilder => routeBuilder.Routes.Add(new CustomRouter(routeBuilder.DefaultHandler)));
```

**UPD**

Alternative approach is to use `MapDynamicControllerRoute`. Something along this lines:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<MyDynamic>();
// ...
app.MapDynamicControllerRoute<MyDynamic>("/{*internalid}");

public class MyDynamic : DynamicRouteValueTransformer
{
    public override ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(HttpContext httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        if (values.TryGetValue("internalid", out var value) && value is string s && s == "777") // simulate some search for id
        {
            values["controller"] = "Home";
            values["action"] = "test";
        }
        return new ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary>(values);
    }
}
```

Note that since you are still using the default routing pipeline this looks like security through obscurity which in general is not a good approach and probably you should better implement appropriate security restrictions (you should not rely on the "impossibility" to guess the actual routes).

Comment: Thanks for youre reply. The constructor of my `IRouter` implementation requires another IRouter (the DefaultRouter) so that it can pass the Route onto that. In earlier days there was an option to register an `IRouter` with app.UseMvc() which hat a configure option providing the DefaultRouter. app. How could I get hold of the DefaultRouter to pass into my custom router when using your solution?

Comment: @Mats and one more.

Comment: Thanks again! Using Mvc (and no endpoint routing) did the job. And yes, I know that its hiding the urls  is just some added obfuscation and exactly that is what I need. There also is the regular authentication/authorization in place. ;)